# Getting parameter types from parameterised dynamic query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm writing an interface to provide end-user input around a query.
An administrator defines the query, eg:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 + col5 AS sumcol
FROM mytable
WHERE col10 = @parm1 AND somethingelse > @parm2
```

Now I can parse that query in C# getting all the returned column names

```
using (myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
{
    //Retrieve column schema into a DataTable.
    schemaTable = myReader.GetSchemaTable();

    //For each field in the table...
    foreach (DataRow field in schemaTable.Rows)
    {
        // Display one-liner of important fields
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - Base Table: [{1}]  Data Type: [{2}]", 
            field[schemaTable.Columns["ColumnName"].ToString()].ToString(),
            field[schemaTable.Columns["BaseTableName"].ToString()].ToString(),
            field[schemaTable.Columns["DataType"].ToString()].ToString()
            );
    }
```

But I also want to get the data types that the parameters @parm1 and @parm2 are expecting. I can parse the string ok to get the parameter names, but I want to present to the end user input boxes for the 2 parameters and check they are the correct types before executing the query to get the results. There isn't necessarily a specific column name which I can check, eg is it was always colx = @parm1 then I could check the type of colx and assume @parm1 would be the same type, but the clause is likely to be often more complicated than that.
I don't have control over what query the admin creates, but I want to try to make it as fool proof as possible for the end user, prompting them to enter the correct type for the parameters, because I can't be sure the administrator is going to give sensible names to the parameters to indicate what the query expects. When I pass the query to SqlServer to get the return column types is there are way that it can also tell me what the parameter types might be?
I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 and above you can use [sp_describe_undeclared_parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878260(v=sql.110).aspx) stored procedure to guess parameter types.

For example, the following query executed on the Northwind sample database:

```
EXEC sp_describe_undeclared_parameters 
        N'SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID'
```

Gives you the following result:

```
+-------------------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| parameter_ordinal |    name     | suggested_system_type_id | suggested_system_type_name | suggested_max_length | suggested_precision | suggested_scale | suggested_user_type_id | suggested_user_type_database | suggested_user_type_schema | suggested_user_type_name | suggested_assembly_qualified_type_name | suggested_xml_collection_id | suggested_xml_collection_database | suggested_xml_collection_schema | suggested_xml_collection_name | suggested_is_xml_document | suggested_is_case_sensitive | suggested_is_fixed_length_clr_type | suggested_is_input | suggested_is_output | formal_parameter_name | suggested_tds_type_id | suggested_tds_length |
+-------------------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|                 1 | @CustomerID |                      239 | nchar(5)                   |                   10 |                   0 |               0 | NULL                   | NULL                         | NULL                       | NULL                     | NULL                                   | NULL                        | NULL                              | NULL                            | NULL                          |                         0 |                           0 |                                  0 |                  1 |                   0 | NULL                  |                   239 |                   10 |
+-------------------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Ah, that look interesting. Thanks I'll give that a go.